# Cross-site Search

Tags: feature-request, search, stack-exchange, android-app, ios-app

**I propose the ability to search across all sites from the Feed page on the app.**

Sometimes I have an off the wall question, but I am not sure which site I would find the information on, or even if there is a site. It is sometimes painful to go searching though the sites when I am not sure what I am looking for. For example, "What would happen to time if our Gravity was greater?". (Not a lot of thought put into this example question.) Do I search in Physics? World building? Or perhaps the answer is in the movie site with an Interstellar reference.  Maybe the answer is in a site I haven't heard of.

I am not sure how painful this feature would be to add, and it may not be feasible. But I think it would be awesome and useful.

Answer (score -3):

You can use [this third party tool](https://www.google.com/) to search for content across all of the SE sites.

If you *really* want to search from within the site, you can simply go to [the search page](https://stackexchange.com/search).

Comment: My question was about adding it to the app, not searching for alternatives